# Create a Case with SOAP in PHP - Failing to map across Contact ID

Tags: soap-api, case, sobject, php, php-toolkit

I have created a connection via SOAP with PHP and I am trying to create a new Case when the user submits the form.  I have the SFDC Contact ID of the user and I am trying to insert the Contact Id into the **Contact** field.

Contact is a Lookup(Contact) field.

Here is my code

```
$sObject = new stdclass();
        $sObject->Contact = '00390000002XUAx';  // Test Victor
        $sObject->Product__c = '01t9000000568wx';  //Test LBD
        $sObject->EventProgram__c = '7016F0000025iQx';  //Test LBD - 15/03/2018
        $sObject->Permission_to_use_in_Marketing__c = 'True';
        $sObject->Description = 'Testing the Case with test text.';
        $sObject->Subject = 'TEST SOAP - F2F Eval';
```

I am getting the following error:

> **** Creating the following: stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => No fields provided in an external foreign key reference in entity: Contact [statusCode] => INVALID_FIELD ) ) [id] => [success] => )

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be populating the Contact Id on `Contact` whereas the standard Contact lookup field on Case is named as `ContactId`. And that’s what the error seems to be complaining about as there’s no such field named `Contact` on Case.

Changing the field to `ContactId` should resolve your issue. You can find the standard fields on Case in its [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm).

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  Also that is a great resource, I was looking in SFDC object field list and couldn't see the ContactId field.